# How to use string.format for below give string?

Tags: java, string

How to use string.format for below given string?  I want the json value to be dynamic so getting the values in string and formatting it.

```
String json = "{ \"asin\":\"" + rs.getString("asin") + "\", \"appdetails\": { \"asintype\":\""
            + rs.getString("asintype") + "\",\"app_name\":\"" + rs.getString("appname") + "\", \"app_username\":\""
            + rs.getString("appusername") + "\",\"app_password\":\"" + rs.getString("password")
            + "\",\"service_provider_uname\":\"" + rs.getString("serviceid") + "\",\"service_provider_password\":\""
            + rs.getString("providepassword") + "\",\"marketplace\":\"" + rs.getString("marketplace")
            + "\" , \"accountname\":\"" + deviceDataRS.getString("accountname") + "\", \"deviceusername\":\""
            + deviceDataRS.getString("deviceusername") + "\", \"devicepassword\":\""
            + deviceDataRS.getString("devicepassword") + "\", \"networkname\":\""
            + deviceDataRS.getString("networkname") + "\", \"networkpassword\":\""
            + deviceDataRS.getString("networkpassword") + "\"} }";
```

Comment: Please consider that this isn't a unique problem; it's so common that you should never need to explicitly create this string...

Comment: Oh then how to do this, can you please help me with an example?

Comment: @user3782636 please checkout my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is certainly possible to write JSON by using `String.format()`, writing JSON is such a common operation that there exist many libraries that will handle it for you. This is preferable because it is easy to make a mistake when you do it yourself, especially later on, when you haven't touched the project in a while and you change your code.

Consider using a library like Jackson. You would start with an object that contains all of your data.

```
class Data {
  public String asin;
  public String asintype;
  public String appname;
  // ...
}
```

Then you can "marshal" the object to JSON:

```
Data data = new Data();
data.asin = "foo";
data.asintype = "bar";
data.appname = "baz";

// Jackson JSON object mapper
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// write to file
mapper.writeValue("c:\\data.json", data);

// write to string
String str = mapper.writeValueAsString(data);
System.out.println(str);
```

Mkyong has a [good tutorial](https://mkyong.com/java/jackson-how-to-parse-json/) that illustrates this in more detail.

Using `String.format()` you would do something like this:

```
String.format("{\"asin\":\"%s\",\"asintype\":\"%s\"}", data.asin, data.asintype);
```

And I hope you can see how complicated that will get with a large object, and how careful you have to be with escaping your quotes and maintaining the correct JSON structure. It's a pain. Don't do it!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement a couple of years back when I had to form a JSON as String using the `ResultSet` values fetched from `Database` provided without creating any `POJO` class or `Object to JSON conversion` dependencies. Then I used a fabulous Apache Commons library called `commons-text` and [org.apache.commons.text.StringSubstitutor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html) class from that library to replace dynamic placeholder values in String. The library can be added to your project as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Below code-snippet is all you required to replace placeholder values dynamically in String.

```
String json = "{ \"asin\":\"<asin>\", \"appdetails\": { \"asintype\":\"<asintype>\"," +
                "\"app_name\":\"<appname>\", \"app_username\":\"<appusername>\",\"app_password\":\"<password>\"," +
                "\"service_provider_uname\":\"<serviceid>\",\"service_provider_password\": \"<providepassword>\"," +
                "\"marketplace\":\"<marketplace>\", \"accountname\":\"<accountname>\", " +
                "\"deviceusername\":\"<deviceusername>\", \"devicepassword\":\"<devicepassword>\", " +
                "\"networkname\":\"<networkname>\", \"networkpassword\":\"<networkpassword>\"}}";

        Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
        values.put("asin", rs.getString("asin"));
        values.put("appdetails", rs.getString("appdetails"));
        values.put("asintype", rs.getString("asintype"));
        values.put("appname", rs.getString("appname"));
        values.put("appusername", rs.getString("appusername"));
        values.put("password", rs.getString("password"));
        values.put("serviceid", rs.getString("serviceid"));
        values.put("providepassword", rs.getString("providepassword"));
        values.put("marketplace", rs.getString("marketplace"));
        values.put("accountname",  deviceDataRS.getString("accountname"));
        values.put("deviceusername",  deviceDataRS.getString("deviceusername"));
        values.put("devicepassword",  deviceDataRS.getString("devicepassword"));
        values.put("networkname",  deviceDataRS.getString("networkname"));
        values.put("networkpassword",  deviceDataRS.getString("networkpassword"));
String finalJson = StringSubstitutor.replace(json, values, "<", ">");
```